# Printing values of array using pointers in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Pretty basic question. The trick is that the array is defined as a 2D array.

```
int main(){
    int mat[3][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 9; index++){
        // only change code below this line
        // print the value at this index using pointer arithmetic

        //below is my code
        printf("%p\n", *(&mat + index));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to pointers. From what I understand, the '&' pointer points to the address, and the * pointer points to the value in that address, right?

The output should be the integers 1-9 on a separate line

Comment: `&mat + index` is undefined behavior unless `index == 0` or `index == 1`.  `*(&mat + index)` is undefined behavior unless `index == 0`. `printf("%p\n", *(&mat + index));` is undefined always.

Comment: use `printf("%d\n", *((int *)&mat + index));` to get the intended behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int mat[N][N] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N * N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ",  *( *( mat + i / N ) + i % N ) );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Another approach is to reinterpret the two-dimensional array as a one dimensional array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int mat[N][N] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N * N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ",  *( ( int * )mat + i ) );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 ) printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you need that all the integers would be outputted in one line then just remove the if statement.